# ORDER BY with two columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables in the mysql database:

1. trips(id,name,desc,createdat)
2. trip_ratings(id,ratingvalue,tripid,userid)

I want to **get 100 most recent trips sorted by higher average ratings.**

I have tried following mysql query:

```
SELECT AVG(ratingvalue),tripid,tripcreatedat FROM trip_ratings 
                                        INNER JOIN trips on trip_ratings.tripid = trips.id
                                        GROUP BY trip_ratings.tripid
                                        ORDER BY AVG(ratingvalue) DESC, tripcreatedat DESC
                                        LIMIT 100
```

But as it sorts by rating value first I only get trips sorted by higher ratings.

Is it possible within a single query? can anyone hint me what should I do?

**EDIT:** example:
I have data in trip_ratings table like this:

[image]

and from my tried query I can get results like this.
[image]

But my problem is: **Get 100 most recent trips sorted by higher average ratings.**

Instead of downvoting and close votes, can anyone have any solution for that or can anyone give me a hint that is it possible within a single query? thanks.

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: @juergend I have already put desired result. and ok, wait, I'm editing

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande *"you can order by only one column"* - Untrue. Here, Google "multiple order by mysql" and you'll see many results.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes you are right. I found the solution by searching that we can order by multiple columms.

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande , helo you `CAN` order by 2 columns , mySQL will check if its possible to order by both columns , if not it will order by 1st column specified.

Comment: @Krupal Glad to hear you found your solution, *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- umm... I am not talking about actual solution. I was talking about ur comment. by the way, I got the data only sorted by average rating values as I mentioned. Do you have any solution?

Comment: @Krupal I was confused by the comment you left: *"I found the solution by searching that we can order by multiple columms."* - That's why I thought you had found your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use an inline view, to first get the "100 most recent trips".

Then join that to `trip_ratings`, to calculate the "average rating" and order by that result.

```
SELECT m.id AS tripid
     , AVG(r.ratingvalue) AS average_rating
     , m.tripcreatedat
  FROM ( SELECT t.id
              , t.tripcreatedat
           FROM trips t
          ORDER BY t.tripcreatedat DESC
          LIMIT 100
       ) m
  LEFT
  JOIN trip_ratings r
    ON r.tripid = m.id
 GROUP BY m.id, m.tripcreatedat 
 ORDER BY AVG(r.ratingvalue) DESC
```

If there are multiple trips that have the same average rating, it's indeterminiate what order those will be returned in. You can add other expressions to the order by to make it more deterministic.

```
 ORDER BY AVG(r.ratingvalue) DESC, m.tripcreatedat DESC, m.id DESC
```

---

This isn't the only way to do it. There are other approaches that will achieve an equivalent result.

Comment: @Krupal: a few errors in my first go around (missing GROUP BY clause, wrong qualifier on column reference), those are now fixed.

Comment: its ok...using inner join instead of left join works fine. is there any importance of left join here?

Comment: There would be a difference if there were any "most recent" rows in `trips` that didn't have any associated rows in `trip_ratings`. With the `INNER JOIN`, those rows from `trips` wouldn't be returned. The `LEFT JOIN` returns the rows from `trips` even if there aren't any associated `trip_ratings` rows. For your use case, it may not make any difference. In the more general case, the difference could be significant.